# Discord.j: Cannot read property 'hasPermission' of null

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Before I explain the issue, I'd like to mention that I've tried looking at other stack overflow questions similar to this one, but all of them seem to have solutions that I've tried and haven't worked. Also, I'm not the most experienced when it comes to JavaScript, so sorry if this is just a simple mistake I was too stupid to notice.

Now, to the issue:

I have this bit of code:

```
client.on('message', function(message)
{
    if (message.member.hasPermission('BAN_MEMBERS'))
    {
        return
    }

    // deal with message
})
```

And I keep getting this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasPermission' of null

I do in fact realize that message.member is most likely null, I'm just not sure how and why.

As mentioned at the top, I've tried many solutions but none of them worked. Another interesting thing to note is that the entire bot worked about 2-3 months ago, and then suddenly it just stopped working properly. (Yes, I'm on the most recent version of discord.js)

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using `console.log` to see what type of message is causing the error? Perhaps there's a specific type of message that does not have a member.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the way that you are handling the message is what is causing the error. Below is a method that's [asynchronous](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/asynchronous), meaning this won't block the code until it's finished. It's similar and should help with the issue

```js
client.on("message", async message => {
    if(message.member.hasPermission("BAN_MEMBERS") {
        return;
    }
});
```